# operation bump sequence status

Tags: javascript-sdk

I am using latest stellar js library. However operation.BumpSequence is failing.

Unhandled rejection TypeError: sdk.Operation.BumpSequence is not a function.

As per the roadmap, bumpsequence operation should be available by now.

Can someone confirm if its working and also how to track the feature request ?

Comment: Stellar-core with this feature has not been released yet.

Comment: technically it is has been available since early April but only on private test networks running master (and Horizon support was added 3 weeks ago as well). I think the question might be related to the support for BumpSeq in the Javascript SDK ?

Answer (score 2):

BumpSequence was activated on testnet Aug 17th, with the upgrade to protocol version 10.

(The JavaScript SDK has had the `bumpSequence` operation for a while already)